# Android sdk main.out.xml parsing error

Tags: android

I just started a new Android project, helloword" to continue learning Android development and I got stumped compiling the default 'helloword' compile / run. I think that I missed a step in configuration and setup, but I am at a loss to find out where. I have an AVD configured, set and launched.

When I press 'run as', i can not find android2.1 simulator.and find these errors:

```
[2012-07-25 08:59:49 - helloword] res\layout\activity_main.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_main is already defined.
[2012-07-25 08:59:49 - helloword] res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-07-25 08:59:49 - helloword] E:\android软件开发\新建文件夹\helloword\res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-07-25 10:03:12 - helloword] /helloword/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
[2012-07-25 10:03:13 - helloword] /helloword/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
[2012-07-25 10:03:15 - helloword] File is Out of sync
[2012-07-25 10:05:13 - helloword] /helloword/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
[2012-07-25 10:08:44 - helloword] activity_main.out.xml is out of sync. Please refresh.
[2012-07-25 10:08:45 - helloword] activity_main.out.xml is out of sync. Please refresh.
```

Comment: Do You have Android item under Window->Preferences? Have You tried launch run (Ctrl+F11 from java file, not xml)? And, remove activity_main.out.xml file - it's wrong one and usually generated when try to launch run from xml file.

Comment: read this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3767

Answer (score 27):

It is not your fault. When you try to compile a android project from its **xml resource** , eclipse considers it as executing xml file and so you get some output from it, in the same name of the xml with **.out.xml** extension.

To avoid this, you have to **right click the project** and select **run as -> Android Application** for the first time and then follow the below steps,

> Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Operation -> Always Launch the previously launched application

Once you provide this in the **window->preferences**, from the next time when you press **"run"** or **"ctrl+f11"** from even a xml file, your project will get executed.

**EDIT:** You must also delete *res/layout/*.out.xml*, the file that Eclipse created and you do not need it.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, this fixed it for me.

1. Delete activity_main.out.xml
2. Double click on a .java file
3. Hit F11

Answer (score 0):

Never run your project from xml file .Open your java code then run it...If you run it from xml you will get that error.Its also same for manifest file