# Cannot run my first Hello World In AVD Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to follow the tutorial at [This Link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) and I get the following errors

```
[2012-10-03 22:02:16 - MyFirstApp] res\layout\activity_main.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_main is already defined.
[2012-10-03 22:02:16 - MyFirstApp] res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-10-03 22:02:16 - MyFirstApp] D:\Users\Adam\workspace\MyFirstApp\res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-10-03 22:03:23 - MyFirstApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-10-03 22:04:47 - MyFirstApp] res\layout\activity_main.xml:0: error: Resource entry activity_main is already defined.
[2012-10-03 22:04:47 - MyFirstApp] res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2012-10-03 22:04:47 - MyFirstApp] D:\Users\Adam\workspace\MyFirstApp\res\layout\activity_main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-10-03 22:04:53 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring library 'com.motorola.android.iextdispservice', missing property value
[2012-10-03 22:04:57 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring library 'com.motorola.android.iextdispservice', missing property value
[2012-10-03 22:05:27 - MyFirstApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

I have the following code in my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

      <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />         
</LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone please tell me what is going wrong. I have spend a significant time trying to figure this issue out. Is there something wrong with the configuration ? When I click the run button a file called activity_main.out.xml gets created which is empty.

Comment: please upload androidmanist.xml's code as well.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641967/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error

Comment: delete **activity_main.out.xml** & then clean project-> build project-> run project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run the xml file `activity_main`. Change the focus to any java file or run it from package explorer by right clicking the project and run it. Before doing all this, delete your `activity_main.out` file.

Answer (score 2):

delete **activity_main.out.xml**  and Run -> Run as Android App. would solve this problem.

this problem is caused because eclipse automatically uses XSLT on xml when you press Run. Deleting main.out.xml is annoying, and you could modify launching operation in Windows->Preference->Run/Debug->Launching->Launching Operation->Always launch the previously launched application. (my eclipse version is Indigo JavaEE)

Also check [This](http://situee.blogspot.in/2011/02/unparsed-aapt-error-mainoutxml.html).

Answer (score 1):

Delete the activity_main.out.xml in your project then select the Project -> Clean -> Select Your Project