# eclipse _out xml file

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android sdk main.out.xml parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641967/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error)

sometimes when I'm in the layout xml file and hit the run button accidentally, I get an x_out.xml file created in the directory. Its like if I am in the home.xml and hit run, eclipse creates home_out.xml and its empty do you know why is that happining?

Comment: Happens in my eclipse, too. Still don't know the solution. I have to restart eclipse at that time.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11642813/603744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when you install some of the xml-plugins in eclipse.

If you do not need those xml plugins for other projects you can remove them. Eclipse recognizes the xml files as part of your android project and directly starts the android project

When you click the Run button with an XML file selected, Eclipse is running an XSL Transformation on that XML and producing the .out.xml file as the result. This is a feature of the Eclipse Web Tools feature, which you'll have if you installed the Eclipse for Java EE Developers package (it may be included in other packages, too).

**To Remove this Error -**

> Open the Preferences and navigate to Run/Debug > Launching; there
>   you'll find the option under Launch Operation at the bottom of the
>   window.

Comment: oh ty man thats the answer I was lookin for

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Eclipse to launch your latest launch configuration, instead of attempting to create a launch configuration for the current document/selection. **Under Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching, you can select "Always launch the previously launched application".**

EDIT: You probably have a plugin which defines a launch shortcut which triggers on XML-files. This sounds like a pretty dumb thing to do.

Comment: thank you for this answer its also good to know. When I come to any java files and hit run I can go on launching app so its not a big problem but I would like to know why is that happining? what is the case if you know. and no I dont have any plugin for that I think, but still I will check that.